# Synchronizing against unknown database schema in Android

Tags: android, sql, database, synchronization

I have an online (postgresql) database, and a local copy of the db in an Android app. The data in these is synchronized, so the app can function offline, but can download new data and upload results when it can. Data is transfered via http GET and POST requests.

I have no problem synchronizing the data for known tables, however, I would like it to be possible to create new tables/alter tables in the online database and have that change reflected in the Android db automatically i.e. without having to release a new version with the updated synchronization code. Is there an obvious/standard way to do this that I haven't found? Google searches I have performed just refer to database migrations for two of the same system or for known schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an obvious/standard way to do this that I haven't found?

There's no "standard" way but there are ways to do it depending on your requirements and how your app works.

It's actually a broad question but solvable if you give it a bit of thought.

My app downloads data from a server on a daily basis. Part of the download process involves downloading a DB version file (just a plain text file) similar to the following...

```
db_version=12345
```

...the string representation of the previous version (if any) is saved in `SharedPreferences` as an int value.

If the version in the file is greater than the one in `SharedPreferences`, the downloader pulls some text files which contain SQL commands for creating, dropping, altering tables etc. Only after the changes have been successfully made does the downloader pull the actual data files and update the DB data (not forgetting to update the latest version in `SharedPreferences`).

If the version in the file is the same as in `SharedPreferences`  then obviously the download simply does the normal daily data download and DB data update.